# is there a better way to install a package to a python virtual environment?

Tags: python, pip, conda, arm64

I'm trying to get a three year old GitHub project running on aarch64 and having trouble installing a few packages to a Python/conda virtual environment using pip.

I have completed a modest amount of coursework in Python and have even less experience working with packages and within virtual environments.

While I realize there are newer versions of many of these packages available, I am trying to install the versions as indicated on the GitHub page wherever possible.

One of the packages giving me trouble is scipy (1.1.0), which is a dependency for scikit-learn (0.20.4) and Theano (1.0.3).

pip warned me about support for Python 2.7 so I downgraded pip to an older version.

When pip failed, I further tried installing via conda as well as by downloading the tarball and installing locally via pip (`pip install archive.tar.gz`), both failed.

I was expecting pip to install scipy so I could continue and install the packages that require it as a dependency.

Following are are some more details.  Thanks so much for reading and in advance for any advice!

```
(cxnn) xilinx@pynq:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.15
(cxnn) xilinx@pynq:~$ pip --version
pip 20.2 from /home/xilinx/miniforge3/envs/cxnn/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

```
(cxnn) xilinx@pynq:~$ pip install scipy==1.1.0
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting scipy==1.1.0
  Using cached scipy-1.1.0.tar.gz (15.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  Building wheel for scipy (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/xilinx/miniforge3/envs/cxnn/bin/python2.7 /home/xilinx/miniforge3/envs/cxnn/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpo_PBo1
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9JuC7w/scipy
  Complete output (6600 lines):


*** COMPLETE OUTPUT IS TOO LONG TO BE INCLUDED ***


  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
Failed to build scipy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2; however, version 20.3.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/xilinx/miniforge3/envs/cxnn/bin/python2.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

```
(cxnn) xilinx@pynq:~$ conda install scipy==1.1.0
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - scipy==1.1.0

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-aarch64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: Are you sure the project needs python 2.7? 2.x was already end of life 3 years ago.

Comment: The problem is not with Python, pip or scipy, the problem is processor architecture. [`scipy`==1.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/1.1.0/#files) provides wheels for different Pythons and OSes but only for x86 and x64 platforms. To install on aarch64 you need to compile from sources and that's hard. You'll need to install dependencies, you'll need to find out proper old versions of said dependencies. See https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your replies!

@jordanm the project specifies 2.7.  I haven't tried using a newer version yet but I will try a new virtual environment with whatever current/default versions of Python and the packages are available since I'm having so much trouble.

Comment: @phd I thought I was installing from source by downloading the tarball and installing from the local archive (`pip install archive.tar.bz`).  Thanks for the link, I will try this later and if all else fails I will try current/default version of Python and the packages as suggested by jordanm.

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the GitHub project to venture a guess if this will work or not.